# Решения для создания отчетов и печатных документов

Tags: c#, winforms, report

Есть задача по разработке ПО и большого количества отчетности к нему. Отчетность как печатная (типа Отраслевых накладных и прочего), так и просто "журналы работы пользователя" и т.п.
Подскажите кто в курсе, какие существуют бесплатные решения для коммерческого использования. (Microsoft Report Viewer - не предлагать).

А так же забыл уточнить, проект на WinForms.

Comment: Я в похожем случае пользовался Excel (правда его с нельзя назвать бесплатным решением). Создал в нем шаблон (ну той же накладной к примеру) и вперед. Ну или Word те же возможности дает в принципе. Плюс VBA много приятных сторон имеет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучший выбор в вашем случае, по моему мнению, Crystal Report http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artId=170. Сам пользуюсь им больше 10 лет.

Толковых бесплатных программ, увы, нет..

Вот еще вариант FastReport: https://www.fastreport.ru/ru/product/fast-report-net/

И посмотрите вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp.